# How to measure common coverage for Polymer components + .js files?

Tags: polymer, karma-runner, code-coverage, karma-coverage, wct

How to measure common coverage for Polymer components with all `.js` files in solution (for non-component tests QUnit is used)?

I tried [karma-coverage](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-coverage), but it works only for `.js` files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Polymer components there is a solution to measure common coverage with `karma-coverage`: split to .js files and include it to components. Example is [here](https://github.com/rcosnita/polymer-karma-example)

Answer (score 2):

For Polymer, you would normally use [`web-component-tester`](https://github.com/Polymer/web-component-tester) (WCT) to test your components, and the [`web-component-tester-istanbul`](https://github.com/thedeeno/web-component-tester-istanbul) plugin for code coverage. You'd configure `wct.conf.json` in the root of your project with something like this:

```js
{
  "suites": [
    "test/components/my-view1/my-view1.html"
  ],
  "plugins": {
    "istanbul": {
      "dir": "./build/coverage",
      "reporters": [
        "text-summary",
        "lcov"
      ],
      "include": [
        "*.js",
        "*.html"
      ],
      "exclude": []
    }
  }
}
```

And then run `wct`, which outputs something like this:

[image]

Unfortunately, a recent upgrade in WCT has made the coverage plugin [incompatible](https://github.com/thedeeno/web-component-tester-istanbul/issues/38), such that the plugin never gets called, so coverage is always shown as `100% (0/0)` (no lines covered, no lines seen).

Comment: Thanks, I know about wct and found this issue on GitHub https://github.com/thedeeno/web-component-tester-istanbul/issues/38, maybe I can use the previous version. But did you try to measure coverage with wct for all .js files in solution? (not only for Polymer components)

Comment: Yep, that's the issue I linked to. :) I had no luck trying previous versions of WCT with `istanbul`. I'd be interested in hearing about your experience, especially if you get it working. Yeah, I tried to measure both `*.js` and `*.html`, as in script inside `html` files (see the config's `include` setting).

Comment: For non-component tests I use QUnit but it's not supported in WCT, so the last option is splitting components to .js file and .html file like in answer below